# Conditional vs. Unconditional Variance of OLS Estimator

Tags: statistics, variance, least-squares, linear-regression

Suppose I have the standard OLS estimators for the model: $y=a+bx+{\epsilon}$, where both $y$ and $x$ are random variables. I was informed that the unconditional variance and conditional variances of $\hat{b}$ are not the same.
I have that $V(\hat{b}|x) = \frac{{\sigma}^2}{S_{xx}}$ and I get the same thing for the unconditional variance by using: $V(\hat{b}) = E(V(\hat{b}|x)) + V(E(\hat{b}|x))$.
All of the standard OLS assumptions hold. Where am I going wrong here?

EDIT: Because we condition on $x$, and the estimators are unbiased, it immediately follows that $E(\hat{b}|x)=b$ and $b$ is just a constant, so $V(b)=0$. This just leaves the term for $E(V(\hat{b}|x))$ which should just be $E(\frac{σ^2}{S_{xx}})$. And because we conditioned on $x$ we treat $x$ as "fixed". So this is essentially just the expectation of a constant - so we get that same constant back. I think maybe I don't understand how that expectation is being taken? Can someone confirm that the conditional variance is at least correct (this is essentially straight from the textbook I'm using)?

Comment: Can you show your work after you apply $V(\hat{b}) = E(V(\hat{b} \mid x)) + V(E(\hat{b} \mid x))$? You shouldn't "get the same thing" for $V(\hat{b})$ since this quantity can't depend on $x$ (e.g. via $S_{xx}$).

Comment: Yes. Because we condition on $x$, and the estimators are unbiased, it immediately follows that $E(\hat{b}|x)=b$ and $b$ is just a constant, so $V(b)=0$. This just leaves the term for $E(V(\hat{b}|x))$ which should just be $E(\frac{{\sigma}^2}{S_{xx}})$. And because we conditioned on $x$ we treat $x$ as "fixed". So this is essentially just the expectation of a constant - so we get that same constant back. I think maybe I don't understand how that expectation is being taken?

Comment: You condition on $x$ (actually the i.i.d. sample $x_1, x_2, \ldots$) when you compute $V(\hat{b} \mid x) = \sigma^2/S_{xx}$. But the expectation $E(\sigma^2/S_{xx})$ is taken with respect to the randomness in the sample $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ so this is not the expectation of a constant; the $S_{xx}$ is now random.

Comment: Ok, I think I have a better understanding of what it means to iteratively take expectations (conditionally and unconditionally), and am able to reconcile this now - many thanks! So just to be clear, I get to $V(\hat{b})=σ^{2}E(1/S_{xx})$. Without any more information, we can't take it any further than this, correct?